# Motherboard cannot see Raid Array 3ware 9650SE

Tags: raid, motherboard, raid5

Firstly, I'm new to Servers, Hardware and Raid, so please be gentle.

I am constructing a server with the following specs:

```
 - Motherboard: Asus M5A97 rev 1.02
 - Memory: 32GB
 - Drives: WD20EARX (2GB x 3)
 - RAID: 3ware 9650SE-4LPML
```

So far:
When initially trying to bring the system up, I was unable to get to the RAID card's BIOS, however the Motherboard could see all three harddrives independently.

However, I finally got the RAID card BIOS to load and setup the above 3 drives in a RAID 5 configuration.

I thought that now that this was configured, I would see this RAID Array as a single 4 GB (3.xx Gb in reality) drive that I could now install an OS, etc on.

However, when my system boots up, it doesn't see the drive(s)/array at all. In the MB BIOS I don't see any drives.

I have read the documentation for the RAID card and I am stuck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Anything else I should try? Any more details I can/should provide?

Comment: Do you see the 3ware driver running properly in Linux? Try "dmesg | grep 3w"

Comment: @BernardWei, I ended up booting XenServer install from USB and it saw the RAID Array. Is that normal?

Comment: Once the RAID driver can see the 3ware hardware, you can use their tool to configure it as indicated in the manual. See the section about using their disk manager in http://solitudo.net/hardware/manuals/UsrGuide-9.5.2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Update: not sure how this was fixed, or if it had to do with the fact that I gave up on RAID 5 and ended up putting 2 drives into a RAID 1 array - but it started to work.